# прочесть файл и вывести нужные данные

Tags: php, csv

есть csv файл,в нем есть много разных данных, данные имеют следующий вид.

```
"Почта";"фигня";"еще фигня";"ФИО";"Город";
"i@i.com";"ololo";"....";"Вася";"msk";
"i2@i.com";"ololo";"....";"Петя";"minsk";
```

и тд.
Как вывести толь мыло, имя и город, со всех строк?

Comment: Используйте `fgetcsv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например вот так:

```
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        echo "Почта: $data[0], ФИО: $data[3], Город: $data[4]\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Главное корректно выводить элементы из массива `$data`.